# Importing standalone Google Apps Script to a file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a Google Apps Script file which sort of acts like a Master Code which I would like to use for multiple spreadsheets. Is there a way to 'import' the Google Apps Script or in a sense link it to the spreadsheets so I don't need to keep copy pasting all the code from the Master to the spreadsheets script editor?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options.

1. Publish your script as an Add-on. Read more [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish)
2. Create a script that can work with any spreadsheet (code would get by ID or use the Drive API to browse where it works) from a centralised UI. You can create a simple WEB UI to control it.

Answer (score 0):

Put a minimal script in the sheet and then include and call your "master code" as [a library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries).